# WooCommerce search no results not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with woocommerce search results. The problem is that the "no results" page never appears. When I search for something that I know has no results - it just dumps all products. Example: http://alpha.safetyworks.com/?s=fkjakfjalkfjdlkjfalkjflkaj%3Blkajfd&post_type=product&tags=0&limit=10&ixwps=1

In my child theme, I have a file called woocommerce.php and the code looks like:

```
<?php get_header();
$bloglayout =   neat_get_blog_layout();
?>
<div class="blog-single">
    <div class="container">

        <?php if( $bloglayout == 'l_sidebar' ):?><?php get_sidebar();?><?php endif;?>
        <div class="main-column">
            <?php 
                // get the post.
                if( have_posts() ):
                    // loop the post.
                woocommerce_content();

                else:
                    // nothing found.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                endif;
            ?>
            <?php 
            /**
             * neat_pagination action.
             * hooked neat_pagination, 10
             */
            do_action( 'neat_pagination' );
            ?>       
        </div>
        <?php if( $bloglayout == 'r_sidebar' ):?><?php get_sidebar();?><?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

So from this, I can tell 2 things - one the "have_posts()" function is not working properly AND/OR the function woocommerce_content() is not working.

woocommerce_content() lives on wc-template-functions.php and that looks like

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_content' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output WooCommerce content.
     *
     * This function is only used in the optional 'woocommerce.php' template.
     * which people can add to their themes to add basic woocommerce support.
     * without hooks or modifying core templates.
     *
     */
    function woocommerce_content() {

        if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

            endwhile;

        } else { ?>

            <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

                <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); ?>

            <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

            <?php endif;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: woocommerce.php does not generate the search results. Your child theme should have a `search.php`

Comment: Well that's what I would have thought but it is not the case as I have removed search.php and searchform.php from the parent and child themes (just to test). The minute I remove woocommerce.php, the search fails - error page.

Comment: does your theme offer woocommerce support? or is this something you added? what did your child themes search.php look like? did it say anything like `<?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); endwhile; ?>` `<?php else: wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('siteurl').'/404', 404); exit; endif; ?>`

Comment: It does not offer woocommerce support but I have created a ticket directly with woocommerce. the search.php looked like this

   `<?php if( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); endwhile; else: print '<p>'.__('Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms.','neat') . '</p>'; $args = array(); wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters( neat_tag_cloud_args' , $args) ); endif; ?>`

Comment: if your theme does not offer woocommerce support, I am assuming you added woocommerce.php to your child theme? you will need to add some functions to functions.php to enable woocommerce support on your theme

Comment: Yes, that is correct that we added this file. Which functions specifically would I need to add?

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: Ok just to report back - I'm waiting on WooCommerce. They have confirmed an issue with their Instant Product Search. However, following the documentation provide by @RobBenz, I was able to get the normal WooCommerce Product Search up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue directly related to WooCommerce Instant Product Search extension - version 1.8 fixes this bug.